# Redirect in WP, add a notice after

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce

I'm still relatively new to working with PHP, so bear with me!

Currently using WooCommerce with WordPress, and am attempting to redirect customers directly to the cart and apply a notice to the cart page, when they attempt to add the same product twice.

```
// Downloadable/virtual qty check
        if ( $product_data->is_sold_individually() ) {
            $in_cart_quantity = $cart_item_key ? $this->cart_contents[$cart_item_key]['quantity'] : 0;

            // If it's greater than 0, it's already in the cart
            if ( $in_cart_quantity > 0 ) {
                wp_redirect( 'MySite.com/cart' ); exit;

                wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add another &quot;%s&quot; to your cart. You have been redirected to your cart for purchase.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_title() ) ), 'notice' );
            }
        }
```

I'm aware that the above if statement isn't correct. I'm just trying to show what it is I am trying to accomplish. To elaborate:

- The theme I'm currently using does not have integrated pages for WooCommerce. The author has offered lousy support thus far and wants additional payment for the integration. Not doing it.
- As a result, I am attempting to hide all aspects of my shop. I have pricing tables set up that when the Purchase button is clicked, the "product" is automatically added to the cart and they are redirected to the cart for purchase.
- When a user attempts to add the same package twice, it redirects back to the individual product page and adds an error notice that they're unable to do that. Remember, I'm using the link that is typically displayed via the Add to Cart button on the product page, with my pricing tables. This is why it dumps me back to the shop page.
- I'd like to add a notice to the top of the cart page AFTER they are redirected, informing them of *why* they were redirected.

Apologies for the wall of text. I'd much rather get as much info provided in the OP than leave people trying to discern what I'm asking.

On a final note, yes I've attempted creating a support topic on the WooCommerce plugin page, but they've only bothered answering just 100 of their last 1k support topics. Both my wife and I's recent support requests have sat for weeks. I'll never find a resolution there.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You pretty much had it. I think the reason you couldn't get it to work is because that hidden little `exit;` bit on the same line of the redirect. You need to add a notice using `wc_add_notice`, do the redirect, then exit the script.

```
        if ( $in_cart_quantity > 0 ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You cannot add another &quot;%s&quot; to your cart. You have been redirected to your cart for purchase.', 'woocommerce' ), $product_data->get_title() ) ), 'notice' );
            wp_redirect( 'MySite.com/cart' ); 
            exit;                
        }
```

One more tip: instead of using a hard-coded url in your redirect, use this: `wp_redirect( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() );`

Comment: the notice will not appear in the redirected page